# MVC RouteConfig routes one path to Controller but not another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two routes mapped in my RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Content",
        url: "Content/{item}.css",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Content",
            action = "GetContent"
        }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Reports",
        url: "SubFolder/App/Views/OtherFolder/Reports/{report}.html",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Reports",
            action = "GetReport"
        }
    );
}
```

For a URL like

> http://example.com/SubFolder/App/Views/OtherFolder/Reports/someReport.html

The 2nd Route correctly fires off the `GetReport` method in `ReportsController`:

```
public ActionResult GetReport(string report) { .... }
```

But for a URL like

> http://example.com/Content/app.css

I would expect the 1st Route to fire off the `GetContent` method in `ContentController`:

```
public ActionResult GetContent(string item) { ... }
```

but it does not. Any ideas how I can get this routed properly? Ideally I'd like any GET request for anything under the `Content` folder to be routed to `ContentController`, but I'm just starting with css files directly in that folder.

I'm on IIS 8.0, MVC 4.0, and using VS2012 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

By default, MVC does not route static files and just tries to serve a static .css file under the requested path.
Just remove the .css ending and the route will be used.

Edit: To be clearer the IIS tries to serve these static files before the MVC routehandling even comes into play.